# Downgrade debian 10 to 9

Tags: debian, debian-installer, vps

I would like to install a software in my Debian VPS but I found that it only supports Debian 9. Is it possible to downgrade Debian in my VPS?

PS. I would like to install Koha indeed

Comment: You could check if your VPS allows running containers and run this software in a debian 9 container.

Comment: Downgrade isn't a good manner in Linux, recommended is formating then reinstalling desired version.

Comment: @A.B thank you for your reply. But I am new to Linux. Can you clarify what is containers? Do you mean Docker or LXC?

Comment: yes, both of them are intended to run containers. Docker is application and API oriented, LXC is system oriented (and there's LXD which adds an API over LXC).

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading Debian is not supported!

It might be possible to get to something working if you know what you're doing (but your question indicates you don't have that - high - level of skills with dpkg/apt).

As Stephen mentioned in a comment to another answer, you'll have long term support (but only that, if you want to go that way you should learn what that means) for Debian 9 until June of next year.

But are you sure you need this? I'd never heard of Koha before, but searching for it I found a library system that writes "Actively supported for packages: Debian 9/10 (Stretch/Buster)," on their download page, so I would guess their packages can be installed on Buster (Debian 10).
If it's another Koha you need, I would say that only supporting Debian 9 is a sign the project might be more or less dead, which is a reason no to start using it (you'll be in a pretty unpleasant place if you start depending on it, and it can't be run anymore, although virtual machines is almost always an option), but looking for alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with docker. Or a 2nd virtual machine (vps). However

## To answer the question.

The easiest way to up-grade, down-grade, or cross-grade (one distro to another), is to keep your `/home` directory on a separate partition.

## Putting some custom system stuff into home partition

I also keep `/opt` and `/usr/local` on this partition, in sub-directories `/home/system/opt` and `/home/system/usr-local`. I then add sym-links to these from the respective places:

```
rmdir /opt &&       ln -s -t /home/system/opt /opt
rmdir /usr/local && ln -s -t /home/system/usr-local /usr/local
```

## Install by over-writting

Now install the new OS, over-writing the old data.

## However

I would not install the old Debian 9, as security updates will stop soon. Instead if you need the old Debian, then use Docker, and put what you need in it. Or if using a virtual machine, then why not use two.

Comment: LTS will be available for Debian 9 until June 2022.

Comment: @StephenKitt Yes soon, depending on your definition of soon.

Comment: Actually I would like to install Koha, so if I install docker, I can install Koha insides docker?

Comment: Yes you could create an image your self (use an OS base image, and add to it). Or you can use one of the existing koha images. Docker uses a Gnu/Linux OS for the base of each image (but with no Linux kernel: it uses the host kernel).